# Off Diagonal matrix

Tags: math-mode, formatting, matrices

How to write off diagonal matrix in latex?
[image: off Diagonal matrix]
I tried this

```
 \begin{align*}
   \left[
     \begin{array}{ccccc}
        &  &  &  & 1 \\
        &  &  & \ldots  \\
       1 &  &  &  &
     \end{array}
   \right]
  \end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcometo TeX.SE.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `bmatrix` environment from `amsmath` to typeset the matrix, and the command `\iddots` from the package `mathdots` for the dots.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\begin{document}
\[
R_n = \begin{bmatrix}
    & & 1 \\
    & \iddots & \\
    1 & &
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

This could be a solution with less code and beauty:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathdots} % http://ctan.org/pkg/mathdots

\begin{document}

\[
R_n = \left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
        &  &  &  & 1 \\
        &  & \iddots &  & \\
       1 &  &  &  &
\end{array}
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

### Update

Similar types of dots can be found: `\iddots` from `mathdots`, `\adots` from `yhmath` or `\reflectbox{$\ddots$}` from the `graphicx` package.

Check this out:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
Different types of diagonal dots:

\[
  \begin{array}{ll}
    \verb!\ddots! & \ddots \\
    \verb!\udots! & \udots \\
    \verb!\iddots! & \iddots \\
    \verb!\adots! & \adots \\
    \verb!\reflectbox{$\ddots$}! & \reflectbox{$\ddots$}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Snippet:

[image]

This could be more nicer using `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
R_n =\begin{bNiceMatrix}
           &    &          & 1 \\
           &    & \Iddots  &   \\
           &    &          &   \\
        1  &    &          &  
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: In LaTeX document don't use TeX syntax `$$` .

Comment: @Zarko Corrected.

Comment: @zarko you can use nicematrix

Comment: @Sebastiano, this cross my mind, but today is not my day :-(. Please be so kind and wrote an answer with `nicematrix`

Comment: @Zarco I am adding that...

Comment: @mmr, nice extension of your answer. I only wonder why you  simply write `\[
R_n =\begin{bNiceMatrix}
   &          & 1 \\
   & \Iddots  &   \\
1  &          &
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\] ` ? Because of matrix size?

Comment: @Zarko Yes, in deed. is this wrong?

Comment: @mmr, no, it is OK. On the same way as you write answer author of the package.

Comment: @Zarko Actually, I wanted to make it really nicer to look.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what you can do with `{bNiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{bNiceArray}{cccc}
    &  &         & 1 \\
    &  & \Iddots     \\
    \\
  1 \\
\end{bNiceArray}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Great prof. You have a good day